# Why is gravity not a physical property?

Tags: classical-mechanics, gravity

I was just curiously looking at the Wikipedia page for physical properties https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_property and noticed that gravity is not there. Why is that?

Comment: I wouldn't read anything into it. It is just a list of examples, not an exhaustive list. I am sure there are many others missing.

Comment: The Wikipedia page uses the exact expression "Examples of physical properties".

Comment: By "gravity" do you mean the "physical phenomenon of gravitational interaction between two bodies", the "gravitational force exerted by one object on another", the "gravitational charge, e.g., mass of an object (i.e., it's ability to attract other objects gravitationally)", the "acceleration due to gravity on a particular planet's surface", etc.?

Answer (score 3):

A physical property of something is an attribute that is intrinsic to it, like its mass, density, heat capacity, conductivity, etc. Gravity on the other hand depends on *which planet you are standing on* which is not intrinsic to the object.

Comment: If you are the object, yes. It is a physical property of the planet, though, its gravitational field..